# Python Keyboard Library OverflowError only When Packaged

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I'm working on a project that requires the python package "Keyboard" (https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/tree/master/keyboard).

While calling functions using `myscript.py` such as `.hook()` or `.start_recording()` all works fine. Examples:
`keyboard.hook(callback)`, `keyboard.start_recording()`

However, when I package `myscript.py` into `submission.exe` using `cx_Freeze` or `Pyinstaller`, I get a `OverflowError` called from the Keyboard library code's `.listen()` as below.

[image: error message]

What's causing this and how can I fix this? Many thanks!

(I'm guessing this may be due to 32-bit vs 64-bit issues. Still, not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing, but I could imagine this is a case where a 32-bit application does not run on a 64-bit machine.

Looking at the `keyboard` package, it will presumably store and exchange process addresses. On a 64-bit machine, even if you run a 32-bit version of the application, you will still get 64-bit process addresses, which sometimes might be too large to fit into a 32-bit address as required by your application.

If you want to run your frozen application on a 64-bit machine, I guess you need to freeze it using a 64-bit python installation. If this still does not work, it probably means that `keyboard` is not handling 64-bit addresses correctly (it needs to set the `ctypes` type of variables storing addresses to 64-bit integer instead of 32-bit integers). I could not find the information whether `keyboard` supports 64-bit architecture or not.